# javafx - delay beetwen key released and listview selecting cell

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a similiar problem with delay beetwen key released and listview selectings cell. When key up/down is released firstListView is selecting down/up cell, after this secondListView do the same but not in the same time.
I need them to be synchronized. 
Here is a gif (0 professional): https://giphy.com/gifs/9zXCVgV5H6CEXdPrrL (not hyperlink because its not scam or something).
Here is my code:

```
AtomicInteger selectedIndex = new AtomicInteger();
firstListView.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                selectedIndex.set(firstListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
                secondListView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedIndex.get());
            }

        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you are trying to implement a `TableView` using two `ListView`s.... So why not use a `TableView`?

Comment: Because one of this list is checklistview from controlsfx and I dont know checkboxes will work with tableview

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're handling the selection using the key events. However you shouldn't rely on the implementation details of `ListView` for this. Listen to the `selectedIndex` property in the selection model of the `ListView` instead:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    ListView<Integer> lv1 = new ListView<>();
    ListView<String> lv2 = new ListView<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        lv1.getItems().add(i);
        lv2.getItems().add(Character.toString((char) ('a' + i)));
    }

    lv1.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        int index = newValue.intValue();
        if (index < 0) {
            lv2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        } else {
            lv2.getSelectionModel().select(index);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(lv1, lv2));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Probably using a `TableView` would be the better option though.